# How to show app window

Tags: macos

When I change from one running application to another, I no longer see the topmost (or any) window from the new app. I now have to select a window from the menu bar.

This is a new and unwelcome behavior. Until semi-recently, switching to another running app would bring up whatever window was last open. I suspect this is a setting somewhere, but I don't know what or where. Can someone suggest how to change this to the previous behavior?

On MacBook OS X 10.8.2

Comment: DOes this happen for all apps? Are you using spaces with Mission Control?

Comment: Yes, happens with all apps. I have some spaces defined, but as far as I know, it happens in all spaces. It is "new" behavior, but I don't know what prompted the change.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that using command tab to switch to another running app, then using command ↑ (up arrow) displayed the window for the newly active app. To my surprise, I could then get an open window when I changed apps **without** having to repeat the command-up. I have no idea **why** this worked or how I got into the situation in the first place.

Comment: OK, this kind of works. Sometimes. But it definitely is not a "fix" in that the problem returns. I sure could use some help.